# Reading a css file in playwright on nuxt server

Tags: nuxt.js, playwright

I am using playwright `page.addStyleTag({ path: stylePath })` code to add css to a PDF download file. The `stylePath` is something I am not sure how to provided in a nuxt server.

Please suggest how read a css file and put the same path in `stylePath` so the playwright library can read it.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. If you have a CSS file on your server, provide the path as the `stylePath`. You don't have to read the file, the Playwright library does it for you.

Comment: The file is currently in my local system. But in production env it will be deployed. How I can get the relative path and pass it to playwright file ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what the issue is: you get the relative path and paste it in as a string: `page.addStyleTag({ path: "some/path/to/your/css/file.css" })`. If you have different paths between dev and prod, use an environment variable and use `process.env.SOME_CSS_PATH` or a condition to pick between different strings: `page.addStyleTag({ path: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "dev.css" : "prod.css" })`